# Where is the LDAP auth settings stored in the Moodle server?

Tags: ldap, moodle

I have recently updated the Moodle LDAP-auth settings under *Site Administration* > *Plugins* > *Authentication* > ***LDAP Server***

I have done this to change the LDAP server settings from using our old **EDIR** to our new and preferred **AD**.

Now I can't log-in.

I have gone into the db and updated the settings (reverted back to exactly how it was before the changes) in the config_plugins table (mdl_config_plugins), but the change does not seem to have taken effect.

Still getting the error when I try to log in:

> LDAP-module cannot connect to any servers: Server: '[new-ad-server].[business-domain].[foo].[bar]:3268', Connection: 'Resource id #17', Bind result: ''

Not sure why it's still using the "new-ad-server", when I've updated the settings to be our old (working) ldap server...

Obviously, the settings seem to be stored somewhere in cache, or in-memory somewhere, but I can't seem to find it.

**Where are these settings stored in the moodle directory?**

Alternatively, how on earth do I fix this issue when I can't log in (using either ldap, or manual login) to update the settings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right that the settings are stored in mdl_config_plugins, but they are also cached, to make them a bit quicker. Try running php admin/cli/purge_caches.php (on the command line on your server), in order to clear the cached values.

Comment: I had tried that, it worked. Thank you, you have saved me a lot of hassle!